# Use Visual Studio 2012 and cant find project property pages

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I Use Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and try open "project property pages".

I need open the Properties of the project, go to Configuration Properties → General → Platform Toolset. Here switch to any older version of the toolset: Visual Studio 2012 (v110xp),  or any other choice.

This window should look like this:

| "Configuration Properties"
-|General
-|Debugging
-|VC++ Directories
-|C/C++
--|General
--|Optimization
--|Preprocessor
--|Code Generator
--|Language
--|Precomplied Header
--|Output files
--|Browse information
--|Advanced
--|All option
--|Command Line
-|Linker
...

But my version looks like this: 
"project property pages

-|Application
-|Build
-|Build events
-|Debug
-|Resourses
-|Services
-|Settings
-|Reference Path
-|Signing
-|Security
-|Publish
-|Code Analysis

How do I get to the window?

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug on VS2012, it always do this to me.

You **must** use older toolset (or install vs2013).

As you can't change it in VS2012 (property doesn't available), you must change manually project file. Open vcxproj file in a text editor, and change all occurences of

```
<PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
```

by

```
<PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>
```

Then save and reopen the project in VS2012

Comment: Thanks Xaruth! Your advice helped me to run the application in the environment Windows Server 2003.

Comment: But also tried to get here before the project settings; for this was set VS Ultimate 2013.    
My version "project property pages" looks like in VS Ultimate 2012: 

-|Application
-|Build
-|Build events
-|Debug
-|Resourses
-|Services
-|Settings
-|Reference Path
-|Signing
-|Security
-|Publish
-|Code Analysis

Comment: I don't even have a platform toolset section